# Automatic failover - Mongoid 4.0.2

Tags: mongoid

Trying to test automatic failover using Mongoid 4.0.2 gem and using MongoDB 2.4.3

To simulate this I'm using this test code:

```
require 'mongoid'

class TestClass
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: "test", database: "test"

  field :uuid, type: String
end


Mongoid.load!("config/mongoid.yml", :test)

batch = (1..100).map { |x| TestClass.new({ uuid: x })  }
batch.each_with_index { |x, i|
  begin
    x.save
    sleep(5.seconds)
    puts "Saved #{i} records" if i%10 == 0
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e.message
  end
}
```

In between saves, I jumped on my MongoDB and did **rs.stepDown()** on the primary node of my Mongo cluster, unfortunately this results in the following errors in my test app:

```
See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md
for details about this error.
Moped::Errors::OperationFailure
The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command
  @length=68
  @request_id=192
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="test.$cmd"
  @skip=0
  @limit=-1
  @selector={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error 10058: "not master"
```

My Mongoid configuration looks like thus:

```
  test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: test_db
      hosts:
        - 192.168.1.10:27017
        - 192.168.1.11:27017
      options:
        max_retries: 10
        retry_interval: 1
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I thought the Mongoid driver would automatically detect changes in the cluster and automatically retry the request after it updates the cluster state on the client / Ruby side?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Having this exact problem now